# button action not responding iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

When I press the nextButton, which is UIBarButton. Then associated action is not performed.

```
UIButton *nextButton1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[nextButton1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"next.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[nextButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(goToItems) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
[nextButton1 sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *nextButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:nextButton1];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=nextButton;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[nextButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(goToItems) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

you are passing `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`, should be `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`

Answer (score 0):

you passed the forcontrolevent as UIControlEventTouchUpoutside instead of that use

```
[nextButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(goToItems) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[nextButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(goToItems) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious mistake is `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`, you should change it to `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.

But instead of making a separate button and then assigning it as a view to the `UIBarButtonItem`, you can simply make a `UIBarButtonItem` with the desired image and associate the desired action with it.

For example:

```
UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"next.png"]
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                              target:self 
                                                              action:@selector(goToItems)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nextButton;

[nextButton release];
```